# Error in Chrome with dhtmlxGrid and Chrome but no Error in FireFox

Tags: xml, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working my way through the tutorial for dhtmlxGrid 
 http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:how_to_populate_it_with_data and I came across something that odd.

Following the tutorial, I am getting an error on this step with Chrome (Version 23.0.1271.97 m) but it's working just fine in Firefox (17.0.1)

The error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/tools/Apache2.2/htdocs/dhtmlGrid/dhtmlxGrid/step3.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I checked with FireBug on FF and there is no such error. I'm just curious as to why this is working in one browser vs another.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I think.

It seems to work fine when not accessing it from a local file. So if I go through the webserver it will populate. If I open it as a file in the web browser it will throw the error listed above.